# Short but (very) consistent lag spikes after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 I started noticing short but consistent spikes in my daily internet usage (It became most apparent when playing online games through Steam). These spikes occur every ~2 minutes or so and last a few seconds after which everything goes back to acceptable speeds.

When using the ping command against my router I get tons of packets that takes 0.4 to 0.8 ms which is fine. Then when these spikes occur I get roughly 10 packets, all of which takes 200-350 (or more) ms. The thing is that this didn't happen at all with Ubuntu 13.10, I should probably also mention that I'm using internet over Wi-Fi.

I've tried to identify the source of these spikes with nethogs, iftop, wireshark, etherape and whatnot without much success (I've never had to track down similar problems so I might be looking at things incorrectly). Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Could there be anything automated to connect to the internet? (Dropbox, Update manager etc)

Comment: @Tim That's what I'm thinking, but I haven't managed to find anything. But still, this issue didn't exist with 13.10 and I've done pretty much nothing since the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved for me after I disabled the network manager's network scanning behaviour.

Finding this solution was not straight forward. Mostly gamers where noticing and having problems with these spikes, while our use case lies within robotics. Finally, several similar approaches to solving the latency spike issue pointed me in the right direction (looking at you network manager!):

- Replaced network manager with manual configuration thereby eliminating latency spikes: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1714817
- Replaced network manager with WICD thereby eliminating latency spikes:https://steamcommunity.com/groups/homestream/discussions/0/540735426854884989/
- Old bug report about network manager's scanning behaviour causing spikes and crashes: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/373680

My favourite solution in the end is described here: https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/issues/24

**That is, disabling the network scanning by setting the BSSID of your AP in the network manager's setting of your specific WiFi connection.**

I hope this solutions works for you as well!

Answer (score 0):

Shut down every network using resource, and fire up wireshark. See if it's something unexpected that's talking.

I'd also tail /var/log/syslog while things are happening, to see if anything is generated there.

Comment: I closed every network program that I feel safe in terminating; skype, firefox, IRC and whatnot and ran Wireshark on all interfaces solely during the spike. A few SSDP with the text "Windows Peer Name Resolution Protocol", an ARP broadcast from the router "Who was XXX, Tell *thisComp*" and a UDP packet containing some data with the info column saying "Source port: XXX, Destination port: YYY" (XXX, YYY are port numbers, not sure if they're relevant)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like a wifi driver issue. To identify or eliminate this possibility, try using a USB wifi dongle. If the problem goes away, then you have a wifi driver bug.

Comment: I've thought about this as well, unfortunately I don't have access to a dongle. But in the event that it is a wifi driver bug, it seems pretty odd seeing how it worked fine in 13.10. Meaning that 14.04 introduced a new bug or dropped support?

Comment: Wifi dongles that support Linux are remarkably cheap nowadays. Try looking for ones that support the Raspberry Pi. Another option is to try the old kernel on the new release to test, and if that works then bisect (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBisection) to find the point that caused a regression. Regressions in less commonly used drivers can certainly happen, since few kernel developers are likely to notice. And sure - if this has happened, then you have a bug.

Comment: By this point I'm pretty confident in that it's some sort of WiFi related driver bug since using a wired connection eliminates the behaviour. But I don't really feel confident enough to be exploring the corners of my system to find the cause. My laptop is using "AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter", would I be able to download any package with firmware updates or anything similar which might solve the issue?